# python celery db update, where is the password executed

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a python application using celery for my distributed tasks.  I am in need of better understanding on securing my application and where worker gets it's classes.

So I have a tasks.py file and I start the worker on computer 192.168.0.10

```
from celery import Celery
import peewee
from models import Album, Artist

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@192.168.0.10//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
     myDB =peewee.MySQLDatabase(host="xyz.com",port=3306,user="dunker",passwd="myscret",db="mydb")
     conn = myDB.connect()
     ....
```

starting the worker on 192.168.0.10:
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info

On another computer 192.168.0.100 I want to connect to the task

file my_app.py

```
from tasks import add
add.delay(4, 4)
```

So when I execute the add.delay on 192.168.0.100 is the database information (myDB) within tasks.add being sent to the worker on 192.168.0.10 from 192.168.0.100 or is the worker already have that information when it was started

My big question is, do I have to have the database username and password on the two computers for the object myDB?  Can I just have the computer that is running worker have the database passwords?

Thanks for the help, 
a

Answer (score 0):

The worker has the username and password in the code it is executing.

No code is sent from the client to the worker - just the name of the task and the parameters for the task are included in the request.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, that is what I thought, I had to look into it.